# Who is the white sleeper in Fairest #1?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, fables-comics, fairest

In *Fairest* #1, Ali Baba finds two sleeping beauties:

> one the color and warmth of early autumn, while the other is the glistening brilliance of midwinter's deep snow.

The bottle imp tells him that the "auburn-haired babe is the correct one", and indeed she

> wakes up

at the end of the issue.  The issue cover features an auburn-haired girl waking up, so I presume she is indeed Briar Rose (the enchanting Sleeping Beauty), who, according to the summary:

> was stolen away by the goblin army in *Fables* #107.

So who, then, is the other sleeping lady, the one in white?

Comment: I haven't read *Fables*, BTW.  I'm guessing that the answer is contained in there.  However, maybe the answer is going to be revealed in a later *Fairest* issue, in which case that's a valid answer (and it can be updated once we know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Steve Sunu](http://www.comicbookresources.com/author/steve-sunu), writer for Comic Book Resources, said [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/SteveSunu/status/181802988791279616) that this is:

> Lumi, the Snow Queen

Lumi first appeared in *Fables* #38 (August 2005), more info on her can be found [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Snow_Queen_%28Fables%29).

She looks like:

[image]